# Stripplot showing mean+sd [r]

Tags: r, panel, lattice

Hi I want to plot a stripplot showing the mean+sd. I cannot show a boxplot because I have less than 5 values, so I want to use mean and sd. My problem is that I cannot calculate the mean and sd INSIDE the group, rather I get two means that are represented in both groups and and the same with segments.

```
require(lattice)

stripplot(l ~ Medium, parameters,

       ylab=list(expression("lag phase - h"),cex=1.5),
       xlab=list("Medium", cex=1.5),
       auto.key=list(columns=2, rectangles=T, points=F, pch=16, at=NULL ),
       ylim=c(-2,15),
       up=parameters$l+parameters$sd.l,
       lo=parameters$l-parameters$sd.l,
       panel=function(x,y,up,lo,...){
         xj=jitter(as.numeric(x), factor=0.5)
         panel.stripplot(xj,y,pch=16 , alpha=0.5 , factor=0.2,
                         cex=1.2 , ...)
         panel.abline(h=0,col="black",...)
         panel.arrows(x0=xj, y0=lo,
                      x1=xj, y1=up,code=3,
                      angle=90, length=0.05
                      ,alpha=0.5)
         panel.dotplot(x=x, y=tapply(y,x,mean), col="red")
         panel.segments(x0=x,x1=x,y0=mean(y)-sd(y),y1=mean(y)+sd(y),col="red")
       }


)
```

Comment: Without any data (e.g., `parameters`) we can't see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you condition on `Medium`, that is `~l|Medium` rather than `l~Medium` you can calculate mean and sd for each level within the panel function.

For example

```
stripplot(~Sepal.Length|Species,iris,
  panel=function(x,y,...) {
     m=mean(x)
     panel.stripplot(x,y,...)
     panel.stripplot(m,y,pch="|",cex=2,col=2)
  }
)
```

Otherwise you can calculate mean and sd for each level outside of `stripplot`, using `by` or `aggregate` or similar and then add these to the plot.